# Using sgen in MonoTouch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

I know that from Mono 2.8 was introduced a new generational garbage collector.
I set the MONO_ENV_OPTIONS (--gc=sgen) environment variable in my Mac OSX 
to use the new gc.
But I was not able to find any info about how to publish an iPad App 
with this setting.
Any feedback?
Regards

Fabio D'Antonio

Answer (score 3):

MonoTouch up to version 3.x is still based on the Mono 2.6 release.   Support for SGen is something that is planned when we upgrade MonoTouch to the Mono 2.10 runtime.

When we publish that release, there will be a UI for settings this in MonoDevelop

Comment: Now that 4.0 is out, I see the option for sgen in MonoDevelop but it's disabled. Any update on this? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You can check the information here [on monotouch site](http://monotouch.net/Roadmap)

Bring Mono's new generational GC to the iPhone it is still on the roadmap so maybe this isn't supported yet, hope someone from the MonoTouch Team can give us more info about this topic.

Also Upgrading runtime to Mono 2.8 still on the roadmap.

Alex